# How to get the return value of one node.js method in another nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, apigee

I have 2 node.js scripts in Apigee Node.js ABC and Node.js DEF.
Now ABC is the main script and DEF is an object script. I have a method DEFMethod in DEF which returns the status code. I am trying to call that DEFMethod in ABC and DEFMethod return a value which should be passed to ABC. After ABC gets that value it proceeds accordingly.
But I am having issue in passing the value. The check is always undefined.

This is how I call DEFMEthod it in ABC script

```
ds = new DEF(req, resp);
check = ds.DEFMethod(select_contact,resp);
```

DEF script

```
function(error, response, body) 
        {
            if(response.statusCode == 200) 
            {
                //go back 
                console.log("Response:",body);
                console.log("Status Code:",response.statusCode);
                return resp.sendStatus(200);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Response:",body);
                console.log("Status Code:",response.statusCode);
                return resp.sendStatus(404);
            }
        });
```

Please let me know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will return the value you need asynchronously:

**Example:**

DEF script

```js
function(error, response, body) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //go back 
      console.log("Response:", body);
      console.log("Status Code:", response.statusCode);
      resolve(resp.sendStatus(200));
    } else {
      console.log("Response:", body);
      console.log("Status Code:", response.statusCode);
      reject(resp.sendStatus(404));
    }
  });
})
```

ABC script

```js
ds.DEFMethod(select_contact, resp).then(result => {
  check = result;
})
```